80's-90's YA book set in a dystopia where people are shot with tracker guns and explode
I read this book probably in the early 90's, got it from the public library so it might be from the 80's. The setting was dystopian, similar to the Hunger Games, with a group of children (possibly orphans) and an older man who looked after them. They were hunted by government police, and shot with guns whose bullets were tracker pellets. If you got hit by a tracker, it scanned your body and collected data from your brain, then you swelled up and exploded.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Were the protagonists living in an urban environment or wilderness?  How old were the children?  Why were they being hunted?

Part of me wants this to be the Unwind trilogy, but the unwinding is done via surgical procedure. The guns are tranq guns. Otherwise, matches with kids being watched over by an older gentleman in a remote place.

"If you got hit by a tracker, it scanned your body and collected data from your brain, then you swelled up and exploded.": "Tracker" seems a very strange thing to call something that functions that way. Is that what the book called them?

@DavidW - it was set in an urban environment

@ChristopherJamesHuff I'm sure that's what it was. The guns injected some sort of technology that scanned the person,  got their information,  transmitted it back to the 'government'  and then the person swelled up and exploded. It happened to one of the main supporting characters.  There was an emotional goodbye between him and the lead where he told her to get lost before she got his body parts on her.
